# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout with Toolbar and TabLayout

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm making an application which uses CollapsingToolbarLayout with Toolbar and TabLayout.

I want to place the TabLayout to below Toolbar when the header is collapsed.

However, When I try to scroll the view, TabLayout overlays the Toolbar like this linked picture:

[image: However, When I try to scroll the view, TabLayout overlays the Toolbar like this linked picture]

I want to make it like this linked picture when I scroll:

[image: I want to make it like this linked picture when I scroll]

My code for the layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/header"
                layout="@layout/partial_mypage_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/mypage_header_height"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/orange"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/button_back"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_large"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_back"
                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/mypage_toolbar"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_text_appearance"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: if you have Toolbar and TabLayout below, what is collapsing? If you dont want Toolbar and TabLayout to stay there even when you scroll content, put the Toolbar outside CollapsingToolbarLayout, you don't need that

Comment: I tried it with a vertical LinearLayout but when I scroll, the toolbar overlays tablayout

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/partial_mypage_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/mypage_header_height" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_back"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_large"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_back" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/mypage_toolbar"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_text_appearance"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I want to use CollapsingToolbarLayout and place the toolbar to top of screen(pinned)

Comment: It will be pinned in this code as well, only header layout will be scrolled.

Comment: I tried it already but it looks weired. toolbar and tablayout is attached but it is on bottom of screen

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using expedient. I made 2 toolbars including the original one. and I made one of those transparent. then, It looks working fine but I think it is not clear way.